# How get result from method using another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have method **test()** in **Otherclass** class, that returns **String** result:

```
public class Otherclass {
    int i = 0;

    public String test()
    {       
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                 System.out.println("GoToThread");
                 while(i < 10) {
                    i++;
                    System.out.println("value "+i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                   
                }
            }               
        });
        t.start();

        String result = "result value i = "+i;

        return result;
    }
}
```

I invoke this method from main class

```
Otherclass oc = new Otherclass();
System.out.println(oc.test());
```

and want get result as `result value i = 10`
   But thread in **Otherclass** run after returning of methos result, and i get result as:

```
result value i = 0
GoToThread
value1
value 2
value 3
value 4
value 5
value 6
value 7
value 8
value 9
value 10
```

Please, help, what ways can i get result of **test()** method after running Thread?

Comment: What exactly do you want in your result. Only last value or every value from 1 to 10

Comment: If honestly I write this example for better understanding of my problem. In really I have app that have method getting image from server and returns ArrayList of titles. But I get empty ArrayLisr before running method with thread

Comment: If you are downloading images inside an android app, you should be using AsyncTask. it starts a separate thread. Yo can do the downloading in the doInBackground() method and get the results in the onPostExecute() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### To Fix Your Code

You need to wait for your `t` thread to finish by using `join()`:

```
t.start();
t.join(); // this makes the main thread wait for t to finish
String result = "result value i = "+i;
```

### Another Option

Consider implementing [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) if you need to return a value from a thread. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Callable<Integer> worker = new Callable<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
      Integer i = 0;

      while (i < 10) {
        i++;
        System.out.println("value " + i);
        Thread.sleep(500);
      }

      return i;
    }
  };

  Future<Integer> result = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(worker);
  System.out.println(result.get());
}
```

Output is:

```
value 1
value 2
value 3
value 4
value 5
value 6
value 7
value 8
value 9
value 10
10
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add t.join() after t.start(). This will make main thread wait till thread 2 ends

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answers above. You could also pass in a callback interface to your test function and handle the value that way.

```
interface Callback {
    public void onValueChanged(String value);
}
public void Test(Callback callback){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
             while(i < 10){
                callback.onValueChanged("Value = " + i);
                i++;
            } 
        }

    });
    t.start();    
}

// Now print the values live from calling the method
Test(new Callback(){
    @Override
    public void onValueChanged(String value){
        System.out.println(value);    
    }
});
```